# Syncevolution (syncevo-dbus-server) autostart in 13.10

Tags: evolution

As stated in [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/syncevolution/+bug/1187326), there are 2 files missing in 13.04 and in 13.10:

```
/usr/lib/syncevolution/syncevo-dbus-server-startup.sh
/etc/xdg/autostart/syncevo-dbus-server.desktop
```

because of what `syncevo` autostart does not work. Is there any way to fix this problem?

Comment: Which version of syncevolution you are using? Why do you need to auto-start it?  Contact mailing list for info.

Comment: 1.2.99.4. Just opened it. Syncevo was forgotten all my settings (i'm using Memotoo for syncing my calendar with Android). Made settings again and turned on autosync. Hope, it will work, because that's what i need: sync my tasks automatically with Evolution.

Comment: Plz update it to 1.3.2 stable from their stable repo.`sudo add-apt-repository deb http://downloads.syncevolution.org/apt stable main`

Comment: @KhurshidAlam
Just updated, thank You! Now it's 1.3.2~1.
  Didn't update from repo above, so i added PPA.
  It does not start automatically.
  In `/etc/xdg/autostart/syncevo-dbus-server.desktop`, in `Exec` section is written: `/usr/libexec/syncevo-dbus-server-startup.sh`.
  In Ubuntu `/usr/libexec/` directory doesn't exist.

Comment: Did you install the package `syncevolution-bundle` (for ubuntu <=12.04) from the ppa? Because if you are installing `syncevolution-evolution` then you won't get dbus-server packages. Also I don't think syncevolution binaries are compiled for Evolution-data-server >=3.6. So you must use Sebastian Heinlein's ppa.Add the ppa from https://launchpad.net/~glatzor/+archive/syncevolution. And then install `sudo apt-get install syncevolution syncevolution-dbus`. In newer version dbus-server can be found under `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/syncevolution/` folder.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SyncEvolution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syncevolution binaries are **NOT** compiled for Evolution-data-server >=3.6. So for Ubuntu >=13.10 you must use Sebastian Heinlein's ppa.

Add the ppa from [launchpad.net/~glatzor/+archive/syncevolution](https://launchpad.net/~glatzor/+archive/syncevolution).

And then install syncevolution using `sudo apt-get install syncevolution syncevolution-dbus`.

In newer version, `dbus-server` can be found under `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/syncevolution/` folder.

Comment: @mackuz you are welcome. If your problem is solved, then accept the answer & close it.